# Next route not working in nested routing?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a component:

```
const ShopPage = ({match})=> {
    return(
        <div>
            <Route exact path={`${match.path}`} component={CollectionOverview}/>
            <Route path={`${match.path}/:id`} component={CategoryPage} />
        </div>
        
    )
}
```

The `CollectionOverview` component is rendered the moment the browser is redirected to the current component as `match.path` is exactly the same path that the browser used to redirect to this component. (i.e) `localhost:3000/shop`. But when I type something like `localhost:3000/shop/123`, I should be redirected to the CategoryPage component right?
That looks like this:

```
const CategoryPage = ({match}) => {
    console.log(match.path)
    return(
        <div className='category'>
            <h2>Category</h2>
        </div>
    )
}
```

But instead, I get a blank page. What am I doing wrong here?
The ShopPage component is getting called from app.js like this:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage}/> 
    <Route exact path='/shop' component={ShopPage}/>
    <Route exact path='/signin' render={() => this.props.currentUser ? 
      (<Redirect to='/'/>) :
      (<SignInAndSignUp/>)} 
      />
    <Route exact path='/checkout' component={Checkout}/>
  </Switch>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to remove `exact` from the Route of the ShopPage component.
So, from this:

```
<Route exact path='/shop' component={ShopPage}/>
```

To this:

```
<Route path='/shop' component={ShopPage}/>
```

And it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap Router and Switch component to the CategoryPage route and Overview route. It works for me before.

```
    const ShopPage = ({match})=> {
        return(
          <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path={`${match.path}`} component={CollectionOverview}/>
                <Route exact path={`${match.path}/:id`} component={CategoryPage} />
            </Switch>
         </Router>        
        )
    }
```

Comment: Adding exact to it doesn't help. It would only help if there was some component using the path generated as a base URL. Placing it here doesn't change anything. And why should I place it at the "lowest part". That's the problem nesting solves right?

Comment: i saw you have already got your answer, i was looking at my old project where i use react router and saw i added a router and a switch before nesting the child routes.